# Why does RewriteRule works only for non-existing file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is a common problem, and there many common answers for this, but I have a specific small detail that does not work and reading documentation does not help me to understand the reason.

So, here is the problem: I want to remove `www.` from a domain name. I use `.htaccess` with mod_rewrite.  Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.swedish\-cloud\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/swedish\-cloud\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

It works, if I just type `http://www.swedish-cloud.com`.  It changes it to `http://swedish-cloud.com`.

But if I type, for example: `http://www.swedish-cloud.com/index.html`, it does *not* change the URL to `http://swedish-cloud.com/index.html`

However, if I type a path to a non-existing file, like `http://www.swedish-cloud.com/index2.html`, it change the URL to `http://swedish-cloud.com/index2.html` showing a *404 Not Found* error.

Can you please let me understand what I am missing? Thank you.

PS: I don't have the root access to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give you the correct answer.  Your syntax for the cond is wrong but not significantly and the syntax for the rule is also wrong.  Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.swedish-cloud.com
RewriteRule ^.*          http://swedish-cloud.com/$0   [R=301,L]
```

Use an equality operator in the cond if that is want you want to do and then you don't need to escape the match string.

The replacement string doesn't need  quotes or escapes and since you want the entire URI, why not just use $0 (the entire match pattern).

Comment: I have changed to the code you suggested, but still not effect. http://www.swedish-cloud.com/index.html does not change to http://swedish-cloud.com/index.html  Only when it is http://www.swedish-cloud.com/ it changes to http://swedish-cloud.com  But I don't say that your code does not work. I tried it on the other Linux server and it works. It seems that on this particular server wild card is somehow disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error you are seeing is a standard error.
The reason rewrites aren't working for www.example.com/something.html is because it doesn't match the regex because of the end of line anchor you have. the $ after swedish-cloud.com$. This means nothing after www.swedish-cloud.com will get rewritten because you've essentially terminated the regex at that point.

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1   [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have changed it to RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.swedish\-cloud\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/swedish\-cloud\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]    but is still has no effect. http:// www.swedish-cloud.com/index.html does not redirect to http:// swedish-cloud.com/index.html

Comment: I have found out that this problem happens because of some settings in the configuration of the server, which I cannot change, as I don't have the root assess. Using the same code on other Linux servers would do the job. I guess the WildCard redirect is disabled on the current server. Thanks, anyway!